# App that changes estimote beacon uuid, major and minor

Tags: android, ibeacon, estimote

I know how to use the estimote sdk to alter the beacon's uuid, major and minor values but I was wondering if there exists an .apk that already does this to save me time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change Major, Minor, Broadcasting Power, Advertising interval at [official app by Estimote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estimote.apps.main).
But changing of UUID is possible only by SDK.

Comment: Just to improve the answer; the trick is in the BeaconConnection class http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/

Comment: @gio can't i change the beacon uuid without using the estimote sdk?
If not can you please explain a little why not?

Comment: @zealvault sorry, but not sure about other ways

Answer (score 1):

I leave the code here, maybe someone will find it usefull, It'a pretty much the same for the three of them, only changes the `writeMajor`.

```
private void setMajorID(final int majorid,final Beacon beacon) {

    mMajorsConnection = new BeaconConnection(this, beacon, new BeaconConnection.ConnectionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticated(BeaconConnection.BeaconCharacteristics chars) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Authenticated to beacon: " + chars);
            mMajorsConnection.writeMajor(majorid, new BeaconConnection.WriteCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mAdapter.update(beacon);
                        }
                    });
                    Log.d(TAG, "Successfully writted the major id!");
                    mMajorsConnection.close();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error while writting the major id!");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Authentication Error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected");
        }
    });
        mMajorsConnection.authenticate();
}
```